# How to control the no. of users logged in?

Tags: c#, sql, database, service

I have one windows application at the user side and a web service at the admin side which are connected in the LAN...

when the user runs the windows application there is a login form and when the user logs in a web service call is made and a row (containing details of the user) is dynamically added into the table of the database present at the admin side.

Now I want that only the specified no of users should be able to login i.e. if admin gives 3 users then only 3 users should be able to login and if the 4th user tries to login it should give an error message that no. of users have exceeded. I tried to do this using for loop as:

`for(count=0 ; count<noofusers ; count++)
{
      //code for inserting the row dynamically into database
}`

but here simultaneously 3 rows are added into the database

I want that when 1 user logins 1 row should be added, when another user logins the NOOfUsers should be incremented and 2nd row should be added and so on...finally when 4th user logins he should not be allowed to...

Can anyone please help me with this issue??

Comment: Why not just add a new row when a user logs in, and then when another user tries to log in, check how many rows are in the table? If there are already 3 rows, show the error message.

Comment: In case you haven't already you need to think about how users are counted as no longer logged in. The easy one is of course a logout button but if a user's app is killed without running its login code you may end up with a phantom login floating around that needs to be cleared out.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static object _lock = new object();

public void LogIn(string username, string password)
{
    lock(_lock)
    {
        if (NumLoggedInUsers() >= MaxNumUsers())
        {
            return "Sry dudez, too many userz";
        }
    }
}
```

I'll leave NumLoggedInUsers() and MaxNumUsers as a exercise for the reader.

Note that I locked that check in case 2 people try and log in simultaneously.